# Memory leak on a "return new node" and i can't find a way to fix it

Tags: c++

Got a problem with a function that returns a "new node" and I can't find it. Here's the function:

```
node* append_new_node(node* l, const T& tt) {
    if (l == 0)
        return new node(0, tt);

    node* n = l;
    while (n->next != 0) {
        if (cmp(n->key, tt)) {
            int a= n->counter;
            a++;
            n->counter=a;

            n=0;
            delete n;
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            n = n->next;
        }
    }

    //check per evitare ripetizioni fra numeri uguali consecutivi
    if (!cmp(n->key, tt)){
        n->next = new node(0, tt);
    }
    else {
        n->counter = n->counter+1;
        n=0;
        delete n;
        return 0;
    }
    n=0;
    delete n;
    return l;
}
```

valgrind report:

```
==2481== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2481==     in use at exit: 480 bytes in 16 blocks
==2481==   total heap usage: 81 allocs, 65 frees, 2,440 bytes allocated
==2481== 
==2481== Searching for pointers to 16 not-freed blocks
==2481== Checked 193,240 bytes
==2481== 
==2481== 96 (32 direct, 64 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 10
==2481==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2481==    by 0x404039: huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::append_new_node(huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::node*, Color const&) (huffman.h:311)
==2481==    by 0x402D61: huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::node* huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::build_list<std::_List_iterator<Color> >(std::_List_iterator<Color>, std::_List_iterator<Color>, unsigned int&) (huffman.h:344)
==2481==    by 0x402283: huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::huffman<std::_List_iterator<Color> >(std::_List_iterator<Color>, std::_List_iterator<Color>) (huffman.h:103)
==2481==    by 0x4016F5: do_test() (main.cpp:137)
==2481==    by 0x401BCB: main (main.cpp:192)
==2481== 
==2481== 96 (32 direct, 64 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 10
==2481==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2481==    by 0x404039: huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::append_new_node(huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::node*, Color const&) (huffman.h:311)
==2481==    by 0x402D61: huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::node* huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::build_list<std::_List_iterator<Color> >(std::_List_iterator<Color>, std::_List_iterator<Color>, unsigned int&) (huffman.h:344)
==2481==    by 0x402389: void huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::reset<std::_List_iterator<Color> >(std::_List_iterator<Color>, std::_List_iterator<Color>) (huffman.h:112)
==2481==    by 0x40186F: do_test() (main.cpp:151)
==2481==    by 0x401BCB: main (main.cpp:192)
==2481== 
==2481== 96 (32 direct, 64 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 10
==2481==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2481==    by 0x404039: huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::append_new_node(huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::node*, Color const&) (huffman.h:311)
==2481==    by 0x403363: huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::node* huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::build_list<huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::const_iterator>(huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::const_iterator, huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::const_iterator, unsigned int&) (huffman.h:344)
==2481==    by 0x4023F4: huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::huffman(huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp> const&) (huffman.h:86)
==2481==    by 0x401936: do_test() (main.cpp:159)
==2481==    by 0x401BCB: main (main.cpp:192)
==2481== 
==2481== 96 (32 direct, 64 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 9 of 10
==2481==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2481==    by 0x404039: huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::append_new_node(huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::node*, Color const&) (huffman.h:311)
==2481==    by 0x403363: huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::node* huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::build_list<huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::const_iterator>(huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::const_iterator, huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::const_iterator, unsigned int&) (huffman.h:344)
==2481==    by 0x4023F4: huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::huffman(huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp> const&) (huffman.h:86)
==2481==    by 0x4024B7: huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp>::operator=(huffman<Color, CaseInsensitiveCmp> const&) (huffman.h:135)
==2481==    by 0x401AEC: do_test() (main.cpp:183)
==2481==    by 0x401BCB: main (main.cpp:192)
==2481== 
==2481== 96 (24 direct, 72 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 10 of 10
==2481==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2481==    by 0x40398D: huffman<int, IntCmp>::append_new_node(huffman<int, IntCmp>::node*, int const&) (huffman.h:311)
==2481==    by 0x402687: huffman<int, IntCmp>::node* huffman<int, IntCmp>::build_list<std::_List_iterator<int> >(std::_List_iterator<int>, std::_List_iterator<int>, unsigned int&) (huffman.h:344)
==2481==    by 0x402021: huffman<int, IntCmp>::huffman<std::_List_iterator<int> >(std::_List_iterator<int>, std::_List_iterator<int>) (huffman.h:103)
==2481==    by 0x40151A: dotest_iterators() (main.cpp:113)
==2481==    by 0x401BD0: main (main.cpp:193)
==2481== 
==2481== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2481==    definitely lost: 152 bytes in 5 blocks
==2481==    indirectly lost: 328 bytes in 11 blocks
==2481==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2481==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2481==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2481== 
==2481== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==2481== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
samu@Samu-MS-7821:~/Desktop/test$
```

I'll copy now also other classes named by valgrind

```
  template <typename InIter>
node* build_list(InIter from, InIter to, unsigned int& sz){
unsigned int n = 0;
node* h = 0;
while (from != to) {
  node* tmp;
  try {

tmp = append_new_node(h, *from);

  } catch(...) {
free_nodes(h);
throw;
  }
  if (tmp != 0) {
++n;
h = tmp;
  }
  ++from;
  tmp=0;
  delete tmp;
}
sz = n;

//creo un array di frequenze
int frequenze[sz];
node* scor=h;
int i=0;
while(scor!=0){
    int prova=scor->counter;
    frequenze[i]=prova;
    i++;
    scor=scor->next;
}



//ordino array
insertion_sort(frequenze,sz);


//creo lista ordinata+assegno codifica
node* coded = 0;
string endcode="1";
string midcode="\n";
string code;
for(int q=sz-1;q>=0;q--){
        node* temp;
        code=(midcode+endcode);
         try {
            temp = append_new_node_c(coded, find_freq(h,frequenze[q]), code);
            //std::cout<<frequenze[q]<<"\n";
        } catch(...) {
            free_nodes(h);
            throw;
        }
        coded=temp;
        if(q-1<=0){
            endcode="0";
        }
        else{
            midcode=midcode+"0";
        }

}

h=0;
scor=0;
delete h;
delete scor;

return coded;}
```

another function

```
huffman(const huffman& v)
: head(0), sz(0), cmp(v.cmp){
head = build_list(v.begin(), v.end(), sz);}
```

Really guys, it would be awesome if someone could help me. I cant really find whhat i have to free or delete to prevent this memory leak.
I dont copy all the code cause is about 300 line, but if you need it i will.

Here is the main

```
int main(){ 
try {
do_test();
dotest_iterators();
std::cout << "ok\n";} 
catch (std::exception& e){
std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;}
return 0;}

class Color{
public:
Color(int r, int g, int b): red(r), green(g), blue(b){}

void print(std::ostream& os) const{
os << "Color("
   << red << ", "
   << green << ", "
   << blue << ")";}

bool operator==(const Color& c) const {
return red == c.red && green == c.green && blue == c.blue;}

bool operator!=(const Color& c) const {
return !operator==(c);
}

private:
int red;
int green;
int blue;
};


/* Stampa un'istanza di Color. */
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,
         const Color& c){
c.print(os);
return os;}


struct CaseInsensitiveCmp{

bool operator()(const Color& a, const Color& b) const{
return a==b;}
};


struct IntCmp{

bool operator()(const int& a, const int& b) const{
return a==b;
}
};



void dotest_iterators(){

typedef IntCmp IntCompare;

std::list<int> lista;
int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
a=1;
b=2;
c=2;
d=1;
e=1;
f=7;
g=1;
h=6;

lista.push_front(a);
lista.push_front(b);
lista.push_front(c);
lista.push_front(d);
lista.push_front(e);
lista.push_front(f);
lista.push_front(g);
lista.push_front(h);

//test sul codice
//std::equal_to<int>

huffman<int, IntCompare > codHuff(lista.begin(),lista.end());
//std::cout << codHuff.size() << "\n";
assert(codHuff.size()==4);

//test valori di codifica
codHuff.find(1);
codHuff.find(2);
codHuff.find(6);
codHuff.find(7);}

void do_test(){

typedef CaseInsensitiveCmp ColorCompare;

std::list<Color> lista2;
//creazione lista e test funzione stampa e size
lista2.push_front(Color(255, 0, 0));
lista2.push_front(Color(0, 255, 0));
lista2.push_front(Color(0, 0, 255));
lista2.push_front(Color(255, 0, 0));

huffman<Color, ColorCompare > codHuff2(lista2.begin(),lista2.end());
assert(codHuff2.size()==3);

codHuff2.find(Color(255, 0, 0));
codHuff2.find(Color(0, 255, 0));
codHuff2.find(Color(0, 0, 255));

std::list<Color> lista3;

lista3.push_front(Color(0, 255, 0));
lista3.push_front(Color(0, 0, 255));
lista3.push_front(Color(255, 0, 0));

//funzione reset
codHuff2.reset(lista3.begin(),lista3.end());
assert(codHuff2.size()==3);

codHuff2.find(Color(255, 0, 0));
codHuff2.find(Color(0, 255, 0));
codHuff2.find(Color(0, 0, 255));

//copy constructor
huffman<Color, ColorCompare > codHuff3(codHuff2);
assert(codHuff2.size() == codHuff3.size());

codHuff3.find(Color(255, 0, 0));
codHuff3.find(Color(0, 255, 0));
codHuff3.find(Color(0, 0, 255));


try {
codHuff2.find(Color(0, 3, 255));
assert(0);
} catch(element_not_found&) {
}

//clear
codHuff3.clear();
assert(codHuff3.size()==0);

//swap
codHuff2.swap(codHuff3);
assert(codHuff2.size()==0);
assert(codHuff3.size()==3);

//assegnamento
codHuff2=codHuff3;
assert(codHuff2.size()==3);}
```

I hope u guys can help me

Update: I'll put the all code right here:

```
#ifndef fuffman_h

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

 using namespace std;
/** Versione 2: introduzione degli iteratori. */



/**
 * Eccezione lanciata quando si cerca di inserire una chiave gia'
 * presente.
 */
struct duplicated_element : std::runtime_error
{
  duplicated_element() : std::runtime_error("Duplicated Element") { }
};

/**
 * Eccezione lanciata quando nussuna delle coppie memorizzate
 * corrisponde alla chiave rischiesta.
 */
struct element_not_found : std::runtime_error
{
  element_not_found() : std::runtime_error("Element not found") { }
};


/**
 * Struttura contenente le coppie chiave/valore. NON NECESSARIA?
 */

 /*
template <typename K, typename T>
struct key_value_pair
{
  key_value_pair(const K& kk, const T& vv) : key(kk), value(vv) { }

  template <typename K1, typename T1>
  key_value_pair(const key_value_pair<K1, T1>& p) : key(p.key), value(p.value) { }

  K key;
  T value;
};
*/


/**
 * Un vettore associativo.
 *
 * Contiene coppie chiave/valore di tipo K e T, rispettivamente. Non
 * e' possibile inserire piu' coppie con chiave equivalenti.
 * L'equivalenza tra le chiavi e' definita tramite un funtore
 * specificato dall'utente.
 */
template <typename T, typename Cmp>
class huffman
{
public:

//  typedef key_value_pair<K, T> pair;

  /**
   * Costruttore di default.
   *
   * Il vettore associativo risultante e' vuoto.
   */
  huffman() : head(0), sz(0), cmp() { }

  explicit huffman(const Cmp& c) : head(0), sz(0), cmp(c) { }

  /**
   * Copy constructor.
   *
   * In questa versione l'ordine interno delle copie memorizzate
   * risulta invertito.
   */
  huffman(const huffman& v)
    : head(0), sz(0), cmp(v.cmp)
  {
    head = build_list(v.begin(), v.end(), sz);
  }


  template<typename T1, typename Cmp1>
  huffman(const huffman<T1, Cmp1>& v)
    : head(0), sz(0), cmp()
  {
    head = build_list(v.begin(), v.end(), sz);
  }


  //La funzione prende in ingresso due iteratori puntanti a inizio e fine di una lista e ne creano l'array
  template <typename InIter>
  huffman(InIter from, InIter to)
    : head(0), sz(0), cmp()
  {
    head = build_list(from, to, sz);    
  }

  template <typename InIter>
  void reset(InIter from, InIter to)
    //: head(0), sz(0), cmp()
  {
    if(head!=0){
    clear();}
    head = build_list(from, to, sz);    
  }

  template <typename InIter>
  huffman(InIter from, InIter to, const Cmp& c)
    : head(0), sz(0), cmp(c)
  {
    head = build_list(from, to, sz);    
  }

  /**
   * Distruttore.
   */
  ~huffman()
  {
    free_nodes(head);
  }

  /**
   * Operatore di assegnamento.
   */
  huffman& operator=(const huffman& v)
  {
    huffman tmp(v);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T1, typename Cmp1>
  huffman& operator=(const huffman<T1, Cmp1>& v)
  {
    huffman tmp(v);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
  }



  //???

  /*
  template <typename InIter>
  void assign(InIter from, InIter to)
  {
    huffman tmp(from, to);
    swap(tmp);
  }
    */


  /**
   * Inserisce una nuova coppia nel vettore.
   *
   * Lancia l'eccezione duplicated_element Nel caso in cui la chiave sia
   * gia' presente.
   */

   //E'  UTILE AI FINI DEL PROGETTO? ELEIMINARE O SPOSTARE IN PRIVATE?
   //PER ORA LA TOLGO

  /*
  void insert(const T& t)
  {
    node* r = append_new_node(head, t);
    if (r == 0)
      throw duplicated_element();
    head = r;
    ++sz;
  }
  */

  /**
   *Stampa codifica, dato un elemento.
   *
   * Lancia l'eccezione element_not_found se nessun elemento corrisponde
   * alla chiave specificata.
   */


  void find(const T& t)
  {
    node* n = find_code(head, t);
    if (n == 0)
      throw element_not_found();
    n=0;
    delete n;
  }


  /**
   * Rimuove la coppia corrispondente alla chiave specificata.
   *
   * Lancia l'eccezione element_not_found se nessun elemento corrisponde
   * alla chiave specificata.
   */


   //E' UTILE AI FINI DEL PROGETTO? ELIMINARE O SPOSTARE IN PRIVATE???
   //PER ORA LA TOLGO

  /*
  void erase(const T& t)
  {
    node* n = find_node(head, t);
    if (n == 0)
      throw element_not_found();
    --sz;
    head = erase_node(head, n);
  }
  */

  /**
   * Restituisce il numero di coppie memorizzate.
   */
  unsigned int size() const
  {
    return sz;
  }

  /**
   * Svuota il vettore associativo.
   */
  void clear()
  {
    huffman tmp;
    swap(tmp);
  }

  /**
   * Scambia il contenuto di due vettori associativi.
   */
  void swap(huffman& v) {
    node* tmp = head; head = v.head; v.head = tmp;
    unsigned int tmps = sz;
    sz = v.sz;
    v.sz = tmps;
    Cmp tmpc = cmp;
    cmp = v.cmp;
    v.cmp = tmpc;
  }

private:

  // L'implementazione si basa su una lista a link singolo.  

  struct node {
    node(node* n, const T& tt) : key(tt), counter(1), codifica(""), next(n){ }
    node(node* n, const T& tt, string c) : key(tt), counter(0), codifica(c), next(n){ }
    T key;
    int counter;
    string codifica;
    node* next;
  };


  node* head;  // Puntatore alla testa della lista
  unsigned int sz;  // Numero di coppie memorizzate
  Cmp cmp;  // funtore di confronto tra chiavi


  // Inserisce p in testa alla lista l. Restituisce il nuovo nodo. MI SERVE?
  node* insert_node(node* l, const T& tt)
  {
    node* ret = new node(l, tt);
    return ret;
  }

  //Appendo con codifica
    node* append_new_node_c(node* l, const T& tt, string c)
  {
    if (l == 0)
      return new node(0, tt, c);

    node* n = l;
    while (n->next != 0) {
      if (cmp(n->key, tt)) {
        int a= n->counter;
        a++;
        n->counter=a;
      n=0;
      delete n;
    return 0;}
    else{
      n = n->next;
      }
    }

    //check per evitare ripetizioni fra numeri uguali consecutivi
    if (!cmp(n->key, tt)){
    n->next = new node(0, tt, c);}
    else{
    n->counter=n->counter+1;
    n=0;
    delete n;
    return 0;}
    n=0;
    delete n;
    return l;
  }


  // Append
  node* append_new_node(node* l, const T& tt)
  {
    if (l == 0)
      return new node(0, tt);

    node* n = l;
    while (n->next != 0) {
      if (cmp(n->key, tt)) {
        int a= n->counter;
        a++;
        n->counter=a;
    n=0;
    delete n;
    return 0;}
    else{
      n = n->next;
      }
    }

    //check per evitare ripetizioni fra numeri uguali consecutivi
    if (!cmp(n->key, tt)){
    n->next = new node(0, tt);}
    else{
    n->counter=n->counter+1;
    n=0;
    delete n;
    return 0;}
    n=0;
    delete n;
    return l;
  }


  //implementa qua merge e codifica
  template <typename InIter>
  node* build_list(InIter from, InIter to, unsigned int& sz)
  {
    unsigned int n = 0;
    node* h = 0;
    while (from != to) {
      node* tmp;
      try {

    tmp = append_new_node(h, *from);

      } catch(...) {
    free_nodes(h);
    throw;
      }
      if (tmp != 0) {
    ++n;
    h = tmp;
      }
      ++from;
    tmp=0;
    delete tmp;
    }
    sz = n;

    //creo un array di frequenze
    int frequenze[sz];
    node* scor=h;
    int i=0;
    while(scor!=0){
        int prova=scor->counter;
        frequenze[i]=prova;
        i++;
        scor=scor->next;
    }



    //ordino array
    insertion_sort(frequenze,sz);


    //creo lista ordinata+assegno codifica
    node* coded = 0;
    string endcode="1";
    string midcode="\n";
    string code;
    for(int q=sz-1;q>=0;q--){
            node* temp;
            code=(midcode+endcode);
             try {
                temp = append_new_node_c(coded, find_freq(h,frequenze[q]), code);
                //std::cout<<frequenze[q]<<"\n";
            } catch(...) {
                free_nodes(coded);
                throw;
            }
            coded=temp;
            temp=0;
            delete temp;
            if(q-1<=0){
                endcode="0";
            }
            else{
                midcode=midcode+"0";
            }

    }

    h=0;
    scor=0;
    delete h;
    delete scor;
    return coded;
  }

    //trovo i T dalle frequenze
   T find_freq(node* l, const int f)
  {
    while (l != 0) {
      if (l->counter==f){
      //resetto il counter affinchè non venga ricercato in seguito
      l->counter=0;
    return l->key;}
      l = l->next;
    }
    //return 0;
  }

  const T find_freq(const node* l, const int f) const
  {
    while (l != 0) {
      if (l->counter==f){
        l->counter=0;
    return l->key;}
      l = l->next;
    }
    //return 0; //SERIO PROBLEMA AL RIGUARDO DI CIO PER LE CLASSI/COSTRUTTI che a quanto pare viene risolto restituendo un fico secco
  }

  //STAMPA DELLA CODIFICA

   node* find_code(node* l, const T& t)
  {
    while (l != 0) {
      if (cmp(l->key, t)){
      std::cout << l->codifica<<" codifica \n";
    return l;}
      l = l->next;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  const node* find_code(const node* l, const T& t) const
  {
    while (l != 0) {
      if (cmp(l->key, t)){
      std::cout << l.codifica;
    return l;}
      l = l->next;
    }
    return 0;
  }


  // Cerca k nella lista l. Restituisce il nodo corrispondente, o null
  // se la chiave non viene trovata.
  node* find_node(node* l, const T& t)
  {
    while (l != 0) {
      if (cmp(l->key, t))
    return l;
      l = l->next;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  const node* find_node(const node* l, const T& t) const
  {
    while (l != 0) {
      if (cmp(l->key, t))
    return l;
      l = l->next;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  /// Toglie n da l
  node* erase_node(node* l, node* n)
  {
    node* h = l;

    if (l == n) {
      l = l->next;
      delete n;
      return l;
    }    

    while (l != 0 && l->next != n) {
      l = l->next;
    }
    if (l == 0)
      return h;

    l->next = n->next;
    delete n;

    return h;
  }

  void free_nodes(node* l)
  {
    while (l != 0) {
      node* tmp = l;
      l = l->next;
      delete tmp;
    }
  }

  void insertion_sort(int arr[], int length) {
    int i, j ,tmp;
    for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
            tmp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            arr[j - 1] = tmp;
            j--;
        }
    }
 }

public:


  class iterator
  {
  public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef int distance_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;

    iterator() : n(0) {}

    // iterator(const iterator& it);
    // iterator& operator=(const iterator& it);

    iterator& operator++()
    {
      assert(n != 0);
      n = n->next;
      return *this;
    }

    iterator operator++(int)
    {
      iterator tmp = *this;
      operator++();
      return tmp;
    }

    reference operator*() const
    {
      assert(n != 0);
      return n->key;
    }

    pointer operator->() const
    {
      assert(n != 0);
      return &(n->key);
    }

  private:
    explicit iterator(node* nn) : n(nn) { }

    node* n;

    friend class huffman;
    friend bool operator==(const iterator& a, const iterator& b)
    {
      return a.n == b.n;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const iterator& a, const iterator& b)
    {
      return !(a == b);
    }
  };

  class const_iterator
  {
  public:
    typedef const T value_type;
    typedef int distance_type;
    typedef const T* pointer;
    typedef const T& reference;
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;

    const_iterator() : n(0) {}

    const_iterator(const iterator& it) : n (it.n) { }

    const_iterator& operator=(const iterator& it)
    {
      n = it.n;
      return *this;
    }

    const_iterator& operator++()
    {
      assert(n != 0);
      n = n->next;
      return *this;
    }

    const_iterator operator++(int)
    {
      const_iterator tmp = *this;
      operator++();
      return tmp;
    }

    reference operator*() const
    {
      assert(n != 0);
      return n->key;
    }

    pointer operator->() const
    {
      assert(n != 0);
      return &(n->key);
    }

  private:
    explicit const_iterator(node* nn) : n(nn) { }

    const node* n;

    friend class huffman;
    friend bool operator==(const const_iterator& a, const const_iterator& b)
    {
      return a.n == b.n;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const const_iterator& a, const const_iterator& b)
    {
      return !(a == b);
    }

  };


  iterator begin() { return iterator(head); }
  iterator end() { return iterator(0); }
  const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(head); }
  const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator(0); }

  iterator finditer(const T& t)
  {
    return iterator(find_node(head, t));
  }

  const_iterator finditer(const T& t) const
  {
    return const_iterator(find_node(head, t));
  }
};



#endif
```

Comment: Do you ever `delete` the objects you `new`ed?

Comment: Way to much code.  Use smart pointers.

Comment: I cant use smart pointer, external libraries is not allowed. (its a university project). Anyway, i delete every new except for 
    return new node(0, tt)
and this sort of "return stuff".
The problem is: if memory leak is caused by this return, how can i delete it? 
I delete the variable wich get the return code (after is used) but the program still give me this problem

Comment: Anyway i'm going to update the code right now

Comment: `std::auto_ptr`, despite being somewhat a kludge, is born exactly to handle the "return a pointer to `new`ed stuff", and is available since C++98.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated and should never be used in any new code.

Comment: Check out the order of things, for example:
`n=0;
delete n;`
While for sure it should be
`delete n;
n=0`
First delete, then nullify the pointer. Additionally, You're setting value of n->counter, and right after that you delete the `n`. Why would You do that?! ;)

Comment: You build a list with `append_new_node` and probably other functions. Some object **owns** that list. You must be able to identify that object. (I suspect it's huffman some or another, but it's hard to tell exactly given just a fragment of the full code). That object is responsible for freeing the list at some point, probably in its destructor. (Don't see any destructor code here, so can't tell if it's being done).

Comment: ok. I've added the all code. It's an huffman codifier that's right.
I ve added delete for every new i wrote. I am little bit in panic, so i didnt think about it very well. Anyway also with this change, the code works except for those memory leaks

Comment: If you can use C++11 (and you _should_, really), `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` can help you, they are part of the standard. Don't use `std::auto_ptr`, it's deprecated.

Comment: I can't use it. And its not my choice. I dont make the rules my professore does. unfortunately.

Comment: Please learn how to format your code properly, currently it is **painful** to read.

Comment: Also, it seems like you jumped straight from the algorithm to the code. Doing so in C++ is very dangerous, you should first write some pseudocode and clarify where allocation and _deallocation_ happen, considering all meaningful corner cases.

Comment: Thank you guys all. i found the problem. I use delete instead the right funcion to delete some lists that i use. delete n and n=0 wasn't needed. You all make me thinks about this problem so thanks to all. And I'm sorry about my indentation.

If you want i can post the correct code.

Anyway about the algoritm: you are right. I usually program in java so i dont need to care about allocation and deallocation. My bad. I did exactly like you said. I thought about the algorithm and then go directly to the code.

Comment: Even if you can't use STL, you can still write light equivalent. RAII help to write clean code.

Answer (score 1):

You are nulling a pointer **before** freeing it:

```
n = 0;
delete n;
```

If you pass a null pointer to `delete`, it will simply ignore it and the call results in a nop.

The correct sequence of operations is:

```
delete n; // Free referenced data
n = 0;    // Erase the reference
```

Comment: I didn't read it. Well, I suppose you should post it as an answer too. This solves the memory leak, the algorithm will probably be wrong, but the leak is fixed.